# Unable to submit a simple SnappySQLJob

Tags: snappydata

I am unable to submit a simple job that just performs a System.out.println().  Here is the error I get back from the SnappyData Lead.

```
snappy-job.sh submit --lead 10.0.18.66:8090 --app-name SimpleJobApp
--class snappydata.jobs.SimpleJob --app-jar simpleJob.jar OKOK{   "status": "ERROR",   "result": {
    "message": "null",
    "errorClass": "scala.MatchError",
    "stack": ["spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:244)", "scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)", "scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"]   }
```

## Here is the Job:

```
public class SimpleJob implements SnappySQLJob {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public SimpleJob() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()+" Created");
    }

    @Override
    public Object runJob(Object sparkContext, Config jobConfig) {
        SnappyContext snappyContext = (SnappyContext)sparkContext;
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()+".runJob: executed");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SparkJobValidation validate(Object sparkContext, Config jobConfig) {
        SnappyContext snappyContext = (SnappyContext)sparkContext;
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()+".validate: executed");
        return null;
    }

}
```

## Here is the SnappyData Lead Log:

16/08/05 17:44:07.352 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14 INFO JarManager: Storing jar for app SimpleJobApp, 1052 bytes 16/08/05 17:44:07.368 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19 INFO LocalContextSupervisorActor: Creating a SparkContext named snappyContext1470419047337607598 16/08/05 17:44:07.369 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16 INFO JobManagerActor: Starting actor spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor 16/08/05 17:44:07.371 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16 INFO JobStatusActor: Starting actor spark.jobserver.JobStatusActor 16/08/05 17:44:07.371 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14 INFO JobResultActor: Starting actor spark.jobserver.JobResultActor 16/08/05 17:44:07.371 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO LocalContextSupervisorActor: SparkContext snappyContext1470419047337607598 initialized 16/08/05 17:44:07.375 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16 INFO RddManagerActor: Starting actor spark.jobserver.RddManagerActor 16/08/05 17:44:07.389 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO JobManagerActor: Loading class snappydata.jobs.SimpleJob for app SimpleJobApp 16/08/05 17:44:07.389 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR /tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data/SimpleJobApp-2016-08-05T17_44_07.353Z.jar at http://10.0.18.66:50772/jars/SimpleJobApp-2016-08-05T17_44_07.353Z.jar with timestamp 1470419047389 16/08/05 17:44:07.390 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO ContextURLClassLoader: Added URL file:/tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data/SimpleJobApp-2016-08-05T17_44_07.353Z.jar to ContextURLClassLoader 16/08/05 17:44:07.390 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO JarUtils$: Loading object snappydata.jobs.SimpleJob$ using loader spark.jobserver.util.ContextURLClassLoader@709f3e69 16/08/05 17:44:07.391 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO JarUtils$: Loading class snappydata.jobs.SimpleJob using loader spark.jobserver.util.ContextURLClassLoader@709f3e69 16/08/05 17:44:07.392 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO JobManagerActor: Starting Spark job 376c8d23-6b49-4138-aadd-e4cff8f9f945 [snappydata.jobs.SimpleJob]... 16/08/05 17:44:07.398 UTC pool-29-thread-1 INFO JobManagerActor: Starting job future thread 16/08/05 17:44:07.402 UTC SnappyLeadJobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 INFO JobStatusActor: Job 376c8d23-6b49-4138-aadd-e4cff8f9f945 finished with an error 16/08/05 17:44:07.402 UTC pool-29-thread-2 WARN JobManagerActor: Exception from job 376c8d23-6b49-4138-aadd-e4cff8f9f945:  scala.MatchError: null     at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:244)    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Java program with Scala implementation shows this error. I have written this job in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java program with scala APIs gives this error.I have written SimpleJob in with Java APIs.

```
public class SimpleJob extends JavaSnappySQLJob {

  public SimpleJob() {
    System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()+" Created");
  }

  @Override
  public Object runJavaJob(SnappyContext snappyContext, Config config) {
       System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()+".runJob:    
       executed");
       return null;
  }

  @Override
  public JSparkJobValidation isValidJob(SnappyContext snappyContext, Config config) {
System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()+".validate: executed");
return new JSparkJobValid();
}

}
```

Comment: Great!  That ran.  Follow on question.  The SimpleJob.java uses StdOut.  I don't see that being forwarded to the SnappyData Lead logs.   What Logging API should I use instead, to see my logs show up?  SLF4j?  Regular Log4J?  Java Logging?

Comment: Preferably slf4j (directly using log4j 1.x will also work).